# Beautify the URL for API by .htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, api

Consider that I am requesting this url for a JSON api response.

```
// url that user will type in the browser address bar   
example.com/api/user/0001
```

I have 2 Options:
**Option A**
The redirection will be like this. But The address in the browser will be the same like before.

```
example.com?get1=api&get2=user&get3=0001
```

> The `?get1=xxxxxx` and `&get2=xxxxxx` and is IMPORTANT. if there is more slashes (/) in the url it will add more GET request like this`&get4=xxxxx` `&get5=xxxxx` and so on.

Then I will get the exact information form the `$_GET['reques']` method like this!

```
$var_request = $_GET['get1'];
$var_type    = $_GET['get2'];
$var_id      = $_GET['get3'];
```

**Option B**
The redirection will be like this. But The address in the browser will be the same like before.

```
example.com?request=api/user/0001
```

Then I will get the exact information by exploding the `api/user/0001` like this

```
// Geting request by $_GET
$request = $_GET['request'];

// Exploding by the (/)
$api = explode("/", $request);

// Getting my desired information
$var_request = $api[0];
$var_type    = $api[1];
$var_id      = $api[2];
```

> Remember: The URL will be same as before. It should not look like `?get=` this. The url should be still `example.com/api/user/0001` in the browser url bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **Option B** will be easier to do this. Possible solution is-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)$ ?request=$1 [L]
```

It redirects - `example.com/api/user/0001` to `example.com?request=api/user/0001` Without changing the address in the url bar in you browser.